# Android NavigationDrawer icon displays in grayscale

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I try to create a navigation drawer and it works. However, when the drawer is open, the icons of the items display in grayscale, whereas those icons are in RGB scale. Why this is shows in grayscale?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `itemIconTint` color as below

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       app:itemIconTint="#FF0000"
    />
```

if yoy want to change the **icon** and **Text** color when drawer menu option is selected use drawble

drawer_item.xml

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="true" />
        <item android:color="@color/white" />
    </selector>
```

Nav

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
           app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item"
           app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item"
        />
```

If you don't want to change the icon color 
set

```
 mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Comment: but my concern is that when we set image in drawable in colors form then why it is shows in black  and white?

Comment: but my question is that i don't change the image color of drawable in navigation items, i want only the in drawable image not show actual color they show black and white color, you can see screen sort of naviagtion drawer given above